# What is the best approach for running two separate Tomcat (version 6) instances in one server (linux) ?

Tags: tomcat

What is the best approach for running two separate Tomcat server ? 
The reason for doing so is that I want to separate two web applications and want them to run independently of each other.

It will also be optimum if I can get away without hand-rolling my own tomcat installation. I prefer the stock debian tomcat package, as I will get security/updates from the vendor automatically. But I  would not mind downloading a binary distribution (with all features enabled), and install two separate copies of Tomcat, if that's the only way to go.

Both of the tomcat instances will run behind an Apache server with mod_proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `tomcat6-instance-create` command.

1. Disable the default tomcat6 (you don't want the default instance running if you're doing this). How you do this depends on your distro.
2. Run `tomcat6-instance-create /path/to/config/directory`. This will create an entire new directory structure required to run tomcat, as well as `bin/startup.sh` and `bin/shutdown.sh`. Do this once for each instance you want to create.
3. Edit configs as necessary.
4. Create a new script (or multiple scripts) in `/etc/init.d` that will in turn call the `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` of each instance.
5. Enable them to automatically start when the system boots.

You can read more about this in the man page for `tomcat6-instance-create`